# How to create a Jenkins job and/or user from a dockerfile?

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to set up a customised Jenkins 2 server from a dockerfile.

I use the official image and I want to be able to add things that I need like custom jobs and an admin user.

This is my dockerfile so far:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JENKINS_HOME /var/jenkins_home
ENV JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT 50000

ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000

# Jenkins is run with user `jenkins`, uid = 1000
# If you bind mount a volume from the host or a data container,
# ensure you use the same uid
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${group} \
    && useradd -d "$JENKINS_HOME" -u ${uid} -g ${gid} -m -s /bin/bash ${user}

# Jenkins home directory is a volume, so configuration and build history
# can be persisted and survive image upgrades
VOLUME /var/jenkins_home

# `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/` contains all reference configuration we want
# to set on a fresh new installation. Use it to bundle additional plugins
# or config file with your custom jenkins Docker image.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d

ENV TINI_VERSION 0.9.0
ENV TINI_SHA fa23d1e20732501c3bb8eeeca423c89ac80ed452

# Use tini as subreaper in Docker container to adopt zombie processes
RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/v${TINI_VERSION}/tini-static -o /bin/tini && chmod +x /bin/tini \
  && echo "$TINI_SHA  /bin/tini" | sha1sum -c -

COPY init.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy

# jenkins version being bundled in this docker image
ARG JENKINS_VERSION
ENV JENKINS_VERSION ${JENKINS_VERSION:-2.19.2}

# jenkins.war checksum, download will be validated using it
ARG JENKINS_SHA=32b8bd1a86d6d4a91889bd38fb665db4090db081

# Can be used to customize where jenkins.war get downloaded from
ARG JENKINS_URL=https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/jenkins-war/${JENKINS_VERSION}/jenkins-war-${JENKINS_VERSION}.war

# could use ADD but this one does not check Last-Modified header neither does it allow to control checksum
# see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8331
RUN curl -fsSL ${JENKINS_URL} -o /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war \
  && echo "${JENKINS_SHA}  /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war" | sha1sum -c -

ENV JENKINS_UC https://updates.jenkins.io
RUN chown -R ${user} "$JENKINS_HOME" /usr/share/jenkins/ref

# for main web interface:
EXPOSE 8080

# will be used by attached slave agents:
EXPOSE 50000

ENV COPY_REFERENCE_FILE_LOG $JENKINS_HOME/copy_reference_file.log

USER ${user}

COPY jenkins-support /usr/local/bin/jenkins-support
COPY jenkins.sh /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]

# from a derived Dockerfile, can use `RUN plugins.sh active.txt` to setup /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins from a support bundle
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
COPY plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
COPY install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh

# Add the command line tools
COPY jenkins-cli.jar "$JENKINS_HOME"

# Create jobs
ARG job_name_1="my_super_job"
#ARG job_name_2="my_ultra_job"
# create the jobs folder recursively
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/workspace/
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/builds
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/builds/lastFailedBuild
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/builds/lastStableBuild
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/builds/lastSuccessfulBuild
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/builds/lastUnstableBuild
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/builds/lastUnsuccessfulBuild
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/builds/legacyIds
#RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_2}

## add the custom configs to the container
COPY ${job_name_1}_config.xml "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/config.xml
USER root
#RUN chmod 600 "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/config.xml
RUN java -jar /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 create-job my_super_job < /var/jenkins_home/jobs/my_super_job/config.xml
#COPY ${job_name_2}_config.xml "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_2}/config.xml


# --Install plugins--
# Notice: Deprecated method which however works with a 'plugins.txt' file
#USER root
#RUN chmod 600 /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
#RUN chmod 600 /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh
#RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

# Notice: Recommended method with open case on Github [https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/348]
# Notice: Select whichever plugins you want
#RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh \
#dashboard-view:2.9.10 \
#pipeline-stage-view:2.2 \
#parameterized-trigger:2.32 \
#bitbucket:1.1.5 \
#git:3.0.0 \
#github:1.22.4
# --Install plugins--
```

I have tried to create a job on build time by first launching a container, creating the job manually, saving the `config.xml` file, and then copying it in the image from the `Dockerfile`. Moreover, I am trying to replicate the files/folder structure when a job is being created.

But it is not working. The job is not appearing in Jenkins.

I also tried to use the jenkins-cli.jar, but as I understood , there must be a live Jenkins server to connect to and execute anything which is not the case at build time.

Finally, I suppose creating an admin user in build time must be way more complicated that creating a job...

So, does anyone have any experience on this?

Comment: FWIW, `last*Build` aren't directories; they're symlinks. But you shouldn't have to create any of those directories — placing the `config.xml` is all you need. Are you seeing anything relevant in the Jenkins log during startup?

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of manual stuff. Just use ansible with the role: geerlingguy.jenkins from ansible-galaxy and use the https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/jenkins_plugin_module.html
 and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/jenkins_job_module.html

Comment: Thanks @NehalJWani, I'll try it out